# Fetch whole site python

Tags: python, linux

It's very easy to fetch the simple web page.
As I can see from [python's manumal](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()
```

But how to fetch all site?
Can anybody please provide me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing the site and repeat the process for every link unless it leads you outside of the domain.

Quite straightforward, but it gets complex if you try to fetch also the dynamic content, that does not have links leading to it.

Comment: beautifulsoup is a great tool for this with its `findAll` function. +1

Comment: @Bogdan: No problem, just keep in mind not to fetch something you have already fetched (you can do it by simply saving the pages on the disc with respect to their relative location on the server - this way you would be able to see if the file has been loaded already).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of

- Scrapy  http://scrapy.org/
- BeautifulSoup http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/
- Mechanize http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

You can extract links on a web page and keep track of if you've already visited that page or not and if the url belongs to the same site or not and fetch them.

You need to keep in mind the level of nesting you are going to need in order to index that page. Otherwise, the pages you are going to retrieve will grow exponentially